# Is-it worth to split a page into many pages?

Tags: php

I've got a question about php and pages :
Is-it worth to split the code into many other files ?
So at the end, the index.php would be composed of :

```
include 'footer.php';
include 'header.php';
include 'home.php';
include 'load.php'; 
[...]
```

Or should I put all the code in an unique page ?

Other question, if I include a php page, could all the vars created in the included page be used in the main page, or should-I use $_SESSION ?

Thank you all for your help !

Comment: This is very broad. When you only have one file, putting all code in it shouldn't be a problem - but at the moment you want to reuse parts of your code, splitting it in different files will be much more handy. Is it worth that **to you**?

Comment: It's better approach to proceed that way! And if you create a var in any of them you can use it in the `index.php` where you've included them.

Comment: @SpencerX thank you for your answers ! why am I getting downvoted for a simple question ?

Comment: I guess it's because you would've avoid this question by a simple google search.

Comment: @SpencerX i've had no good answer with those keywords "php worth splitting code" nor "php splitting pages" :/

Comment: @SpencerX that's why I chose to ask your community ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your main question it’s worth. In fact, it will be a pain for you to manage your web page if you don’t follow this method in the long run. I am not a php guy but I can tell you this because this is a universal truth. The idea here is to write once and use anywhere necessary. You don’t want to write the same thing again and again, do you? That’s why we produce function when programming. We define a function and use it as many times we want. Now consider you have suddenly found that you need some modification to do ,  as you have created a function you can make the change in just one place and it will be reflected everywhere without touching a single line of code outside the function’s code. In actual project change is a constant. That’s why we find many design pattern in the software industry like MVC.

In a web project, mostly (not always) the header, navigation, footer are same across all the pages. Therefore, you should consider making different file for these stuff and you should always put your content in your index.php file which are unique for index page.